# Incorrect order of execution of functions when fetching data with Alamofire

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, codable

I just started learning Alamofire(5.0), but I already ran into a problem. The problem is the following: data extraction and assignment of this data to a variable occurs in the wrong order.
Here is my function for data extraction:

```
func fetchForecast() {
        let url = "http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json"
        
        for city in cities {
            let parameters: [String: String] = ["key": apiKey,
                                                "q": city,
                                                "aqi": "no"]
            
            AF.request(url, parameters: parameters)
              .validate()
              .responseDecodable(of: CurrentForecast.self) { (response) in
                  switch response.result {
                  case .success(let value):
                      print("Before appending")
                      self.currentForecasts.append(value)
                      print("After appending")
                  case .failure(let error):
                      print("Failed with error: \(error)")
                  }
                  print("Before printing self.currentForecasts")
                  print(self.currentForecasts)
                  print("After printing self.currentForecasts")
              }
        }
    }
```

I also have a variable in VC to which I add weather forecasts and array of cities:

```
var currentForecasts = [CurrentForecast]()
var cities: [String] = ["Moscow", "London"]
```

I'm calling the data extraction function in viewDidLoad()

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("Before fetch")
        fetchForecast()
        print("After fetch")
        print("Before printing currentForecasts")
        print(currentForecasts)
        print("After printing currentForecasts")
    }
```

But it turns out a strange order of code execution, which can be traced in the report, in the console. Because of this, I have an empty array of forecasts:

```
Before fetch
After fetch
Before printing currentForecasts
[]
After printing currentForecasts
Before appending
After appending
Before printing self.currentForecasts
[Forecast for London]
After printing self.currentForecasts
Before appending
After appending
Before printing self.currentForecasts
[Forecast for London, Forecast for Moscow]
After printing self.currentForecasts
```

Comment: It's the correct order. You are missing the asynchrone concept. You don't read the code linearly, line after line, the closure `{ (response) in ... }` will be called when the request has been made, getting the response from the server (it could take a few seconds, more, etc.)

Comment: I understand what you are talking about, but this entails another problem: when I try to take a value from currentForecasts,  index pot of range happens, since there are no values in this variable.

Comment: Read the value only when you got the response from backend. "Refresh your view" when this happens...  You can add a closure to `fetchForecast()` to be "notified" when you got answer from your API.

Comment: Should I write a completion handler in ```fetchForecast()```, which will tell me when the data extraction from the server is finished? I tried to implement collection view, but when the method returning the number of cells (```return currentForecasts.count```) was called, I got 0. That is, requests (closure ```AF.request...```) didn't have time to execute before calling this method. How can I fix this situation?

Comment: The problem is that the ```completionHandler``` in the ```responseDecodable``` function is ```@escaping```, that is, it is going through the func's lifecycle, and I don't understand how to handle such a situation.